# I have an old question I'd like to move to PLDI

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

Several years ago, I asked the following question on SE:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/376865/what-do-oop-languages-gain-from-having-constructors-that-always-return-an-object

Now that PLDI exists, I think it's a much better fit for it than SE. Are there any steps I can take to migrate it?

Comment: You would need to contact the Software Engineering mods about getting the question migrated - us PLDI mods can't initiate the moving process. For example, you can leave a custom moderator flag explaining that you want to have the question migrated.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works when a question which already has answers is migrated. The people who posted those answers probably do not have accounts on PLDI. The question and its answers also have positive scores on SE.SE, suggesting the question is indeed on-topic there. So perhaps if there is something more PLDI-related you want to know about the topic, which isn't answered on SE.SE, you could instead ask a new question here which focuses on just that aspect.

Comment: @kaya3 this reminds me: There's also the fact that questions can't be migrated after a certain amount of time. The question on SoftEng would be too old to be migrated now, so it would need to be asked anew.

Comment: You are also free to re-post the same question here (Just make sure you disclose that it's a cross post). No need to remove the original question from the other site

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like the policy is "leave it be, repost/reask with a link if there is more to be gained".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is not a good fit for migration, as it would violate several of the [migration guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250):

- **It is too old to be migrated.** Any question that is more than 60 days old can only be migrated by Stack Exchange employees, not diamond moderators, and this only occurs in exceptionally rare circumstances.
- **It already has answers.** From the guidelines:

  > The point of migration is to send the question to a place where it is on-topic and *can* get answered. If the OP already has an answer, then we've already defeated the purpose of migration and the destination site won't have anything to do with the question.

  One problem with migrating questions with answers is that the answers are likely written based on the standards and perspectives of the originating site rather than the target site. In a sense, it is similar to editing one’s question in a way that invalidates existing answers—it’s almost always better to just ask a new question.
- **It would be migrating for the sake of migration.** Again, from the guidelines:

  > We only migrate questions because they are *not a good fit on the original site*. It is perfectly possible for a question to be a good fit on more than one site. It is also possible for a question to be a *better* fit on another site than the one it was posted on. However, those are not reasons to migrate it elsewhere, unless the author specifically requests it. As a general rule, if someone asks a question *here*, and it's not a bad fit *here*, it should stay *here*.

  Admittedly, in this case, you are the author, so you have “specifically requested it.” However, the broader point continues to apply: we generally try to avoid migrating questions unless they are genuinely off-topic on the original site.
- **It might not even be on-topic on PLDI!** We have tightened up [our site’s scope](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since the start of public beta, and we have generally discouraged open-ended questions asking for the pros and cons of a design choice (which can be quite subjective and encourage speculation) in favor of [more specific questions that can receive more focused answers](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/543).

Overall, I think your question is probably actually a better fit on Software Engineering, anyway. They are very good at answering questions about OOP patterns, and much of the design being asked about is really motivated by those patterns. That isn’t to say that there isn’t a reframing of the question that would be on-topic here, so do feel free to ask it if you would like our perspective, too! But be careful to avoid asking a programming question disguised as a language design question.